# How to handle the checkbox with two array and if in one array user on-click the checkbox that should append in second array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

`@complete[]` and `@incomplete[]` are two array then I need to used with these array with checkbox complete array is by default true and incomplete by default false .

```
<%= form_with(model: @task, local: true) do |form| %>
    <% @complete = Array.new %>
    <% @incomplete = Array.new %>

    <% @tasks.each do |task| %>
        <% if task.complete != false then %>
            <% @complete << task.name %>
        <% else %>
            <% @incomplete << task.name %>
        <% end %>
    <% end %>
    <!-- complete task -->
    <%= @complete %>
    <!-- incomplete task -->
    <%= @incomplete %><br>
    <% @complete.each do |i| %><div id = "task_check">
        <%= form.check_boX "@incomplete[]", incomplete.id  %>
        <%= form.check_box "chkbox_ary[#{i}]" , {checked:true} %>
        <%= form.submit "update"%>
        <%= content_tag(:strike, i)%>
        <br></div>
    <% end %>
    <br> <hr>
    <script>
    <% @incomplete.each do |i| %>
        <%= form.check_box "chkbox_ary[#{i}]" %>
        <%= form.submit "update"%>
        <%= i %><br>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

If I check the box as false in complete then it should append to array called complete and if I check the box true in incomplete then it should append to second array called complete.

Comment: follow indentation in html code to maintain readability

Answer (score 0):

if I may, I'd like to point out some stylistic issues in your code first:

- it is unusual to compare with `false`, i.e., `if task.complete != false` should be just `if task.complete` this works thanks to the concept of Truthiness in Ruby
- you can just leave off the `then` in an if-conditional, that's what most Ruby developers do, i.e., `if task.complete then` can just be `if task.complete`
- view templates (`.erb` files) should contain as little logic as possible, i.e., extract the creation of the `@incomplete` and `@complete` arrays into your controller or some other place
- Ruby [Enumerable](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6/Enumerable.html) has many methods to make common work easier, for instance splitting a collection into two collections can be done with `partition`, i.e., you can do `@complete, @incomplete = @tasks.partition(&:complete)` to populate the complete and incomplete arrays (`&:complete` is a shorthand for `{ |task| task.complete }`, google `Ruby symbol to proc` if you want to know more about it)

I'm not sure I understand your question as it is. At the time the complete and incomplete arrays exist no user interaction takes place. I.e., nobody can click anything. When the HTML is rendered, no arrays exist anymore.
So there's two ways I can interpret your question:

1. You wish to move the DOM elements around => you need to use JavaScript for that
2. You wish to partition the checkboxes when the form is submitted => you need to show us the code in your controller that handles the form-submit for us to help you out

Which is it?

PS: I know this isn't an answer right now, but I could not write this as a comment since it's too long and a comment would have been illegible.